# Is there a more efficient way to implement event listeners in nested fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Right now, my application has a single activity and 4 fragments:

1. ViewPager fragment.
2. 2X fragments that contain a RecyclerView each.
3. A details fragment populated on the basis of the item chosen.

I read that it's in good practice to implement listeners to handle events in fragments and let the activity handle events and communication between the fragments. But to make it possible, I've used too many levels of listeners and my code seems to complicated. Is there a better way ? One example of the sequence of listeners is:

Listener in RecyclerView Adapter --> Listener in RecyclerView Fragment -->
Listener in ViewPager --> Listener in MainActivity --> Listener in info Fragment.

And my ViewPager's in a fragment so I could create a flexible UI to support tablets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Eventbus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Have all your fragments and activity register themselves on the event bus. Whenever you want to trigger an event, simply post an event and any fragment/activity that is accepts that event will receive it and react accordingly.

Just name your events appropriately and your code should be easier to understand.